How to clone Universal Robots ROS 2 driver packages grom GitHub?
I am trying to install the Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver package. When following the step 2 Start and Set up, they have mentioned to a way to extract the calibration. However, I tried to clone this UR_Calibration package using git clone -b iron https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/tree/master/ur_calibration. Which gave me this error.  fatal: could not create work tree dir 'ur_calibration': Read-only file system. Then I tried again to clone the whole package using git clone -b iron https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS2_Description.git and it gives the same error. I am unable to use the given script for UR calibration due to this error.
Can you please give me the hidden steps leading to use the script
roslaunch ur_calibration calibration_correction.launch \
robot_ip:=<robot_ip> target_filename:="${HOME}/my_robot_calibration.yaml

Please advice me the way to clone packages from github correctly. Thanks.

You are mixing ROS and ROS 2 versions. roslaunch is from ROS, and Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver is also for ROS (use Universal_Robots_ROS2_Driver for ROS 2)
can you create a folder where you run the git command? The error has nothing to do with ROS.

Thank you for your response and pardon my late reply as I was away for sometime. I tried with Ros2 driver and now I managed to clone all successfully. However when I tried to extract the calibration information from the real robot using the command $ ros2 launch ur_calibration calibration_correction.launch.py 
robot_ip:=<robot_ip> target_filename:="${HOME}/my_robot_calibration.yaml", I get an error "No such file or directory". Could you guide me ?
